# how to match string in "sk_term(" in vi

Tags: linux, vi

I have a sql file where I want to match the string "sk_term(" in the file
when I am using

```
  :/sk_term(
```

it giving the following error

```
  E486: Pattern not found: sk_term(
```

Answer (score 2):

as wbogacz suggested, try using parenthesis

```
:/sk_term\(
```

Comment: giving error  E54 : Unmatched \(

Comment: then is just :/sk_term( (it's the difference between vi and vim)

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis are almost always used as a grouping character, and to find them uniquely you need to escape them to be recognized as a character.